# how to pass parameters to dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I created application of type class library to open RDP

and i want to embed this windows application into a web application but i need to pass server name ,user name and password to the dll as a parameters.

i know that i can use object tag to embedd dll in a web page and PARAM to pass parameters but what i need is to make PARAM value passed by code not static in object tag

```
<OBJECT id="MyWinControl1" height="200" width="200" classid="http:rdp.dll#rdp.rdpControl.cs" VIEWASTEXT>
            <PARAM NAME="IP" VALUE="need to pass it by code from Web page" >
```

how can i do this?

i am using C# ASP.NET 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PARAM NAME="IP" VALUE=<%=value_from_codebehind%> >
```

**codebehind:**

```
//define string named value_from_codebehind
public string value_from_codebehind;
```

after that u can assign values to the `value_from_codebehind`

```
value_from_codebehind = "\"passing_value\"";
```

and this `"passing_value"` with quotas will go to `<%=value_from_codebehind%>`, i.e. u will get

```
<PARAM NAME="IP" VALUE="passing_value" >
```